# How to ensure via shorewall that the network is closed at boot time?

Tags: linux-networking, shorewall

I use [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net) (on Ubuntu 16.04) and would like to ensure that between the start of the boot process and the moment `iptables` rules are applied the network is in a closed state.

There provision for setting such a state in the [`pre-up` section of `/etc/network/interfaces`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution_.231_-_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces) but I would like to keep all my firewall configuration with Shorewall.

Is this possible?

The problem I see is that Shorewall is set to start after networking is up:

```
root@ubuntu ~# grep Required-Start /etc/init.d/shorewall
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs
```

I was wondering if forcing Shorewall to start before `$network` could be a solution, but since this is not a default I fear that there would be unintended consequences of such a change.